# Отложенная конструкция членов класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть C++ класс такого вида. У него есть приватное поле window. И надо бы его в конструкторе моего класса тоже инициализировать как положено. Но тут я натыкаюсь на проблему: просто так взять и присвоить, как это я сделал ниже, нельзя.

Вопрос: как можно?

renderer.hpp

```
#define RENDERER_H

class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer();
    ...
private:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    ...
};

#endif // RENDERER_H
```

renderer.cpp

```
Renderer::Renderer()
{
    sf::ContextSettings contextSettings(24, 8, 2);
    this->window = sf::RenderWindow(..., contextSettings);
    ...
}
```

Comment: так, как вы пытаетесь делать, это не вызов конструктора внутри конструктора, а создание обьекта и дальнейшая попытка присваивания...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Да, название исправил на более подходящее.

Comment: А вот редактировать вопрос, после ответа, не нужно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Из вашего кода не видно, нужен ли вам этот `contextSettings` как самостоятельный именованный объект. Скорее всего не нужен. Тогда, например, так

```
Renderer::Renderer() : window{ ..., { 24, 8, 2 } }
{
  ...
}
```

или, если вам больше нравится,

```
Renderer::Renderer() : window(..., sf::ContextSettings(24, 8, 2))
{
  ...
}
```

---

Если же вам по какой-то причине все таки нужно (или хочется) *отложить* конструкцию `sf::RenderWindow`, т.е. все таки перенести ее *в тело* конструктора, то можно, например, сделать `window` указателем

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> window;
```

и потом в конструкторе делать

```
Renderer::Renderer()
{
  sf::ContextSettings contextSettings(24, 8, 2);
  window = std::make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>(..., contextSettings);
    ...
}
```

---

А также начиная с С++17 вы можете использовать `std::optional`

```
std::optional<sf::RenderWindow> window;
```

и далее в конструкторе

```
Renderer::Renderer()
{
  sf::ContextSettings contextSettings(24, 8, 2);
  window.emplace(..., contextSettings);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Но тогда не учитывается, что `sf::ContextSetting` может инициализироваться как-нибудь динамически и по-разному в зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: @witaway: А где это в вопросе??? Тогда например можно изобрести способ генерировать этот `sf::ContextSetting` на лету в списке инициализации конструктора. Например, можно написать функцию, возвращающую нужный  вам `sf::ContextSetting` по какому-то набору входных параметров.

Comment: Да, правда, в следующий раз буду конкретнее задавать вопрос. В любом случае, получается, этот способ решения проблемы единственный предусмотренный в языке?

Comment: @witaway: См. вторую часть ответа.